# Meaning of ‘walked vaguely’

Tags: meaning

What does it mean to walk vaguely in the following sentence?

> As she walked vaguely up the steps of the building, she shifted the small pot of flowers from hand to hand; then she set it down and remove her mittens before she could open the door.

Comment: What is the source? In a literary sense more context may be needed. Also, did you find any definitions that might fit the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of anyone walking *vaguely*. It sounds as if an inexperienced writer has been casting about for an unnecessary adverb. *Uncertainly* would be better, but nothing would be best of all.

["Show, don't tell."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Show,_don%27t_tell)

Comment: Not purposefully or determinedly, but with vague intent.